# Is there any case that log in or sign up can be a usecase in UML?

Tags: authentication, uml, use-case

I read that log in or sign up can't be a use-case.[Larman: Applying UML and patterns] Is there any case that log in or sign up can be a use-case in a project? How or where do you describe the sign up or the log in in your documentation if not as a usecase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a business perspective they are not use cases. Where is the value of a login? A login on a business level is nothing more than a constraint. You can attach that to the use case (e.g. `«pre-condition» {must be logged on}`).

On a technical level you can describe the login with a use case, though. You need to separate your model with respect to business and technical aspects. So as long as you do not mix both concepts, your model will be fine. Unfortunately UML has no "native" support for that. What I did in the past was to stereotype technical use cases with `«tech»`.

Comment: Even if being a member can have a business value? (E.g. Special offers, valued customer, etc.?) Although that would be probably tied directly to the membership and not login?

Comment: @Peter `become member` is likely a use case (since you get access to things you don't have without). But the login is a constraint which is guarded by the membership.